# C, is it possible to block the process untill the pipe is opened again?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, stdin, named-pipes

I am putting together a server-like process, which receives data from a named pipe and returns some output.

As everybody knows, when the pipe is opened for reading it blocks the process until another process opens the pipe for writing. (Unless nonblock flag is set.)
When another process opens the pipe and writes to it, we can get input like this:

```
...
opened_pipe = fopen(argv[1], "r")
while(1)
   {
   if ( fgets(readbuf, FIFO_READLEN, opened_pipe) != NULL )
       { \\ process the input from the writer  }
   else
       {
       \\ this is the branch when the writer closed his end of the pipe and reader gets EOF
       \\ usually one exits here
       \\ but I would like to freeze the process and wait until another writer comes
       \\ (like a server-like application would do)
       }
   }
```

But when the writer exits this `while` goes into meaningless loop.
It would be better if the reader returned to the initial state - the process is blocked until the pipe gets connected on the other end again. Is it possible to do so?

PS

I tried to create a dummy writer inside my program, which opens the same pipe as `w` and keeps it open in the loop at `fgets` all the time. But it didn't work for me. Maybe I did some mistake. Is it possible to pull this trick?

One also could constantly close and reopen the pipe inside the `while`. But I want to use either `pipe` or `stdin` as the input stream. It would be better to treat them the same way in the program. So, can one reopen the `stdin` stream via `fopen` with some `"stdin"` filename?

Comment: If you're getting into a loop when the writer exits, it means you're not correctly testing for EOF and exiting the loop.

Comment: @Barmar yep, I don't exit the loop on EOF, since I want to wait for another writer to come

Comment: Consider using an `AF_LOCAL` socket instead of a named pipe.  The API is more complicated, but you get a whole bunch of benefits, including: your current problem Just Goes Away; you can reliably talk to more than one client at once; and once you've done this, accepting connections over the 'net is just a small further step.

Comment: thanks for suggestion @zwol
indeed, probably a socket is better suited for the task.. I tried pipes as the easier tool. Definitely gonna learn to use sockets soon :)

Comment: @xealits yep that's what I was suggesting, too, because it really seems like you're after implementing kind of a *service* here. For handling sockets, you need to decide for how to separate the clients ... there are many approaches: the traditional one is `fork()` a child for each client, more modern alternatives are either *event-based* (using for example `select()`) or *threaded* (use `pthread_create()` instead of `fork()`). It's quite some work either way, but you'll have a reliable implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open your FIFO in a server process twice - first for reading, then for writing. Doing this (opening it for writing) will ensure that your process will not see EOF if all clients abandon the FIFO.

Here's the short demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define FIFO_NAME "/tmp/fifo"

int main()
{
    if (mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP) == -1)
    {
        perror("mkfifo");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE *readFd  = fopen(FIFO_NAME, "r");
    FILE *writeFd = fopen(FIFO_NAME, "w");

    char c;
    for (;;)
    {
        c = fgetc(readFd);
        fprintf(stdout, "Read char: %c\n", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this idea (which is indeed awesome). But I probably made some mistake, could not compile and did not pursue it. Is it really possible?

Comment: yep, it worked!
Somehow previously I had a warning about some conversion issues at the second `fopen` and `SIGSEGV` at runtime. Everything is smooth now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question entirely, but in general, when reading from a pipe or FIFO (aka named pipe) that doesn't have a writing end opened, you will read `EOF`. When `fgets()` reads `EOF` this will result in the first byte in the buffer being `0`. You could just check for that and in that case, close the FIFO and reopen it, re-entering your loop.

Something like (sticking with your pseudo-snippet):

```
while (1)
{
    opened_pipe = fopen(argv[1], "r")
    while(1)
    {
        if ( fgets(readbuf, FIFO_READLEN, opened_pipe) == NULL ) {...}
        else if (!readbuf[0])
        {
            fclose(opened_pipe);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**edit:** given your comment here, I get the impression you might want to use a *Unix domain socket* instead of a *FIFO*. Thus, you could `accept()` connections and handle them separately while still waiting for new connections.

Comment: I see. The issue is I don't want to exit when one writer finishes -- I would like to wait for another writer to come. I'll edit the question, since it is indeed not clear from the code snippet. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @xealits Waiting for another writer to come is exactly what this does.

Comment: @xealits well I edited my answer with an alternative that might be better suited for what you want to achieve (if I'm not completely mistaken here)